# Tycho Brahe Danish Astronomer Religious?

Tags: history

Does anyone know if Tycho Brahe was religious?

Answer (score 4):

Like nearly everybody at the time, he "believed in God" and was a member of the Danish Lutheran church.  He from time to time used arguments based on bible verses to back up his solar system model (in which the sun orbits the Earth, and the planets orbit the Sun).  According to Tycho, the idea of a rotating and revolving Earth would be "in violation not only of all physical truth but also of the authority of Holy Scripture, which ought to be paramount."

However he was not notably religious. He was suspected of heresy by some in the Lutheran church. He was not personally on good terms with the local bishops in Denmark. His interest in medicine and astrology were not sanctioned by the church and while he was a follower of Philip Melanchthon, he was not viciously sectarian, at a time when many others were.

He believed in God, but was not especially religious.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.